# REST-Centric web dashboard in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, dashboard

I'm planning to build a REST-Centric web dashboard in PHP. Without connecting to the databases directly. All data 100% comes in and goes out through REST calls alone. I've gone through few framework for writing API like slim, silex, Wave and Lumen, gonna pick one form this (for Azure & MSSQL), My concern is whether developing the Dashboard in Angular or some other js & pure HTML will have any security issue or is it safe to go with Server-side scripts for dashboard too?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I'm doing research for a similar project and this is what I have so far:

All the opensource out there don't fill 100% the needs I have for the project so I can't use them (ie: not mobile ready or not tv ready or poor browser support)

Because of the above, I will need to build a custom solution:

**server side:** Lumen framework for the log in and for securing+processing all the dashboard requests 
**client side:** I will use a angular.js + dashboard template (from envato or from strapui). You can also do it with jQuery.

I hope it helps

Comment: I have just gone through Slim, Silex & wave. Looks reasonable.  I'll look into Lumen & decide.  You got chance to look at these frameworks? If yes please share your thoughts. thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @kaminiVivek there is a benchmark test on the Lumen homepage that convinced me not to look any deeper on slim and silex :) Since I have some experience with Laravel and since the Lavarel documentation is so great.. I think that there is no other option (at least for me). Kamini let me know your opinion on that. Cheers